# Regular expression to analyse COBOL code

Tags: c#, regex, split, cobol

I am currently writing a tool to analyze COBOL code.  For this I need a regular expression to separate individual words, and I am terrible at regular expressions.

I found the following, which works for MOST situations, but not all.

```
string[] words = Regex.Split(line, @"[^\p{L}]*\p{Z}[^\p{L}]*");
```

The problem with this is it's taking fields like ARG-1 and only returning ARG.  It is also not separating something like MY-TABLE(WS-INDEX) into MY-TABLE and WS-INDEX.  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

**Update**

Thanks for all of the insight.  I accomplished what I was looking for with:

```
string[] words = Regex.Split(line, @"\s+");
```

and then I further check the individual words using the Contains() method to see if any of them are a table entry e.g.

```
MY-TEST-TABLE(WS-INDEX)
```

and if they do I substring them to get the 2 pieces.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Is it really possible to use regex instead of a lexer for parsing grammar?

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for the job. You want to find a COBOL parser.

Comment: If you are bad at regular expressions, you shouldn't be attempting to build COBOL analysis tools.  You just aren't ready.    ... You don't say what you want to analyze COBOL code for; if you want to analyze anything more interesting than "list identifiers or comments" in the code, you will need a real COBOL parser.  1) Regex can't do full COBOL parser, b) full COBOL parsers are a LOT of work to do.

Comment: The comments about choice of tool aside, are you sure you've copied your regex correctly to this post? As specified, I don't see how it breaks on a hyphen, since the hyphen doesn't satisfy the mandatory `\p{Z}` in your regex.

Comment: I'm making a tool that confirms that all fields defined in working storage are being used in the program.  This absolutely can be done using Regex.  Peter, yes I copied it straight from the source.

Comment: Sorry for belaboring this, but can you give an example of `line` with hyphens where it returns something other than the first sequence of characters leading up to the hyphen?

Comment: It's a very simple MOVE statement:

MOVE ARG-2 TO R-ARG-2.

Comment: I'm really sorry to say this, but you are going down the road to hell on this one. Regex is simply not up to the task. COBOL is one of the more difficult languages to parse in any reliable way.

Comment: Thanks for you concern NealB, but it's working just fine.  For my application, regex worked just fine.

Comment: "word boundary" regex operators use minus - as one of the many delimiters.  Try `\b(?!-)`

Comment: Determining if a working storage field is used is way harder than trying to decide if its name is used.  First, use of a containing storage field usually means the subfield is used indirectly, often by something else.  Secondly, COBOL has complex rules;  you can leaves parts of a qualified path out, if the result is still unique. You can have two identical identifiers declared in different fields, and a reference that refers to one of them according to COBOL rules but matching just identifiers isn't right. ...

Comment: ... Finally, identifiers are often inserted and/or constructed by COPY/REPLACING statements; extracting identifiers by lexing can't possibly recognized such inserted/constructed identifiers.  So OP's quest to "confirm that all fields defined in working storage are ... used" cannot be done with just identifier extraction (e.g. regexes).   Fundamentally, one needs a full COBOL parser to do this.  If he is happy with something that is 90% correct, doing it his way may be useful.  With possibly thousands of identifiers in a compiled program, I'm pessimistic about his success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool for analyzing the COBOL grammar; however it could be used when splitting the input text into tokens. But even for this much simpler task, Regex alone will not be sufficient. Additional logic will be required.

According to [VS COBOL II grammar Version 1.0.4](http://www.cs.vu.nl/grammarware/vs-cobol-ii/#gdef%3aalphabetic-user-defined-word) an identifier (they call it "alphabetic-user-defined-word") is defined like this:

> ([0-9]+[-]*)*[0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*([-]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)*

This definition is complicated, because it ensures that an identifier contains at least one letter. For splitting this requirement could be dropped. If you do that you get this simple expression for identifiers:

> [0-9A-Za-z]+(-[0-9A-Za-z])*

In order to preserve the delimiters when splitting, just put the delimiter into a capture group (between "(" and ")"):

```
string input = "MY-TABLE(WS-INDEX)";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, "([0-9A-Za-z]+(-[0-9A-Za-z])*)");
```

The result will be (without the quotes):

> ""
>   "MY-TABLE"
>   "("
>   "WS-INDEX"
>   ")"

---

**NOTE**

Many language grammars have nested structures that are defined recursively. Moreover they have special rules for comments and string escapes etc. that make parsing very difficult. Regex can parse such constructs (see [Regular Expression Recursion and Matching Balanced Constructs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)) but the Regex expressions become very complicated and very difficult to understand, because you have to squeeze the whole grammar of the language to be parsed into one single Regex expression. It's as if you tried to write a C# application as one single statement. Use a tool specialized tool like [Irony - .NET Language Implementation Kit](http://irony.codeplex.com/) or [Coco/R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco/R) instead.

Comment: Simple regexes will fail pretty badly at handling column number constraints, string literals (and esp.) continued string literals, which are issues you have to face in just tokenizing the language.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff A;

Take a look at the GNU Cobol parsing code at http://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/gnu-cobol/cobc say starting with http://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/gnu-cobol/cobc/scanner.l

That directory, especially the .l lexical files contain some of the regular expressions, but with supporting context of the formal grammar when combined with the .y bison files.

Or, for quicker immediate feedback, try the Koopa Cobol Parser, at http://koopa.sourceforge.net/ ships as a .jar.

Or, for a poor man's view, the Pygments COBOL syntax highlighter at bitbucket.org under Pygments/lexers/compiled.py

```
class CobolLexer(RegexLexer):
    """
    Lexer for GNU Cobol code.

    *New in Pygments 1.6.*
    """
    name = 'COBOL'
    aliases = ['cobol']
    filenames = ['*.cob', '*.COB', '*.cpy', '*.CPY']
    mimetypes = ['text/x-cobol']
    flags = re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE

    # Data Types: by PICTURE and USAGE
    # Operators: **, *, +, -, /, <, >, <=, >=, =, <>
    # Logical (?): NOT, AND, OR

    # Reserved words:
    # http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/gnucobol/#reserved-words
    # Intrinsics:
    # http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/gnucobol/#does-gnu-cobol-implement-any-intrinsic-functions

    tokens = {
        'root': [
            include('comment'),
            include('strings'),
            include('core'),
            include('nums'),
            (r'[a-z0-9]([_a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9]+)?', Name.Variable),
    #       (r'[\s]+', Text),
            (r'[ \t]+', Text),
        ],
        'comment': [
            (r'(^.{6}[*/].*\n|^.{6}|\*>.*\n)', Comment),
        ],
        'core': [
            # Figurative constants
            #(r'(^|(?<=[^0-9a-z_\-]))(ALL\s+)?'
            (r'\b(?!-)(ALL\s+)?'
             r'((ZEROES)|(HIGH-VALUE|LOW-VALUE|NULL|QUOTE|SPACE|ZERO)(S)?)'
             r'\b(?!-)',
             #r'\s*($|(?=[^0-9a-z_\-]))',
             Name.Constant),

            # Reserved words STATEMENTS and other bolds
            #(r'(^|(?<=[^0-9a-z_\-]))'
             (r'\b(?!-)'
             r'(ACCEPT|ADD|ALLOCATE|CALL|CANCEL|CLOSE|COMPUTE|'
             r'CONFIGURATION|CONTINUE|'
             r'DATA|DELETE|DISPLAY|DIVIDE|DIVISION|ELSE|END|END-ACCEPT|'
             r'END-ADD|END-CALL|END-COMPUTE|END-DELETE|END-DISPLAY|'
             r'END-DIVIDE|END-EVALUATE|END-IF|END-MULTIPLY|END-OF-PAGE|'
             r'END-PERFORM|END-READ|END-RETURN|END-REWRITE|END-SEARCH|'
             r'END-START|END-STRING|END-SUBTRACT|END-UNSTRING|END-WRITE|'
             r'ENVIRONMENT|EVALUATE|EXIT|FD|FILE|FILE-CONTROL|FOREVER|'
             r'FREE|FUNCTION-ID|GENERATE|GO|GOBACK|'
             r'IDENTIFICATION|IF|INITIALIZE|'
             r'INITIATE|INPUT-OUTPUT|INSPECT|INVOKE|I-O-CONTROL|LINKAGE|'
             r'LOCAL-STORAGE|MERGE|MOVE|MULTIPLY|OPEN|'
             r'PERFORM|PROCEDURE|PROGRAM-ID|RAISE|READ|RELEASE|RESUME|'
             r'RETURN|REWRITE|SCREEN|'
             r'SD|SEARCH|SECTION|SET|SORT|START|STOP|STRING|SUBTRACT|'
             r'SUPPRESS|TERMINATE|THEN|UNLOCK|UNSTRING|USE|VALIDATE|'
             r'WORKING-STORAGE|WRITE)'
             r'\b(?!-)', Keyword.Reserved),
             #r'\s*($|(?=[^0-9a-z_\-]))', Keyword.Reserved),

            # Reserved words
            #(r'(^|(?<=[^0-9a-z_\-]))'
            (r'\b(?!-)'
             r'(ACCESS|ADDRESS|ADVANCING|AFTER|ALL|'
             r'ALPHABET|ALPHABETIC|ALPHABETIC-LOWER|ALPHABETIC-UPPER|'
             r'ALPHANUMERIC|ALPHANUMERIC-EDITED|ALSO|ALTER|ALTERNATE|'
             r'ANY|ARE|AREA|AREAS|ARGUMENT-NUMBER|ARGUMENT-VALUE|AS|'
             r'ASCENDING|ASSIGN|AT|AUTO|AUTO-SKIP|AUTOMATIC|AUTOTERMINATE|'
             r'BACKGROUND-COLOR|BASED|BEEP|BEFORE|BELL|'
             r'BLANK|'
             r'BLINK|BLOCK|BOTTOM|BY|BYTE-LENGTH|CHAINING|'
             r'CHARACTER|CHARACTERS|CLASS|CODE|CODE-SET|COL|COLLATING|'
             r'COLS|COLUMN|COLUMNS|COMMA|COMMAND-LINE|COMMIT|COMMON|'
             r'CONSTANT|CONTAINS|CONTENT|CONTROL|'
             r'CONTROLS|CONVERTING|COPY|CORR|CORRESPONDING|COUNT|CRT|'
             r'CURRENCY|CURSOR|CYCLE|DATE|DAY|DAY-OF-WEEK|DE|DEBUGGING|'
             r'DECIMAL-POINT|DECLARATIVES|DEFAULT|DELIMITED|'
             r'DELIMITER|DEPENDING|DESCENDING|DETAIL|DISK|'
             r'DOWN|DUPLICATES|DYNAMIC|EBCDIC|'
             r'ENTRY|ENVIRONMENT-NAME|ENVIRONMENT-VALUE|EOL|EOP|'
             r'EOS|ERASE|ERROR|ESCAPE|EXCEPTION|'
             r'EXCLUSIVE|EXTEND|EXTERNAL|'
             r'FILE-ID|FILLER|FINAL|FIRST|FIXED|'
             r'FOOTING|FOR|FOREGROUND-COLOR|FORMAT|FROM|FULL|FUNCTION|'
             r'GIVING|GLOBAL|GROUP|'
             r'HEADING|HIGHLIGHT|I-O|ID|'
             r'IGNORE|IGNORING|IN|INDEX|INDEXED|INDICATE|'
             r'INITIAL|INITIALIZED|INPUT|'
             r'INTO|INTRINSIC|INVALID|IS|JUST|JUSTIFIED|'
             r'KEY|KEYBOARD|LABEL|'
             r'LAST|LEADING|LEFT|LENGTH|LIMIT|LIMITS|LINAGE|'
             r'LINAGE-COUNTER|LINE|LINES|LOCALE|LOCK|'
             r'LOWLIGHT|MANUAL|MEMORY|MINUS|MODE|'
             r'MULTIPLE|NATIONAL|NATIONAL-EDITED|NATIVE|'
             r'NEGATIVE|NEXT|NO|NUMBER|NUMBERS|NUMERIC|'
             r'NUMERIC-EDITED|OBJECT-COMPUTER|OCCURS|OF|OFF|OMITTED|ON|ONLY|'
             r'OPTIONAL|ORDER|ORGANIZATION|OTHER|OUTPUT|OVERFLOW|'
             r'OVERLINE|PACKED-DECIMAL|PADDING|PAGE|PARAGRAPH|'
             r'PLUS|POSITION|POSITIVE|PRESENT|PREVIOUS|'
             r'PRINTER|PRINTING|PROCEDURES|'
             r'PROCEED|PROGRAM|PROMPT|QUOTE|'
             r'QUOTES|RANDOM|RD|RECORD|RECORDING|RECORDS|RECURSIVE|'
             r'REDEFINES|REEL|REFERENCE|RELATIVE|REMAINDER|REMOVAL|'
             r'RENAMES|REPLACING|REPORT|REPORTING|REPORTS|REPOSITORY|'
             r'REQUIRED|RESERVE|RETURNING|REVERSE-VIDEO|REWIND|'
             r'RIGHT|ROLLBACK|ROUNDED|RUN|SAME|SCROLL|'
             r'SECURE|SEGMENT-LIMIT|SELECT|SENTENCE|SEPARATE|'
             r'SEQUENCE|SEQUENTIAL|SHARING|SIGN|SIGNED|SIGNED-INT|'
             r'SIGNED-LONG|SIGNED-SHORT|SIZE|SORT-MERGE|SOURCE|'
             r'SOURCE-COMPUTER|SPECIAL-NAMES|STANDARD|'
             r'STANDARD-1|STANDARD-2|STATUS|SUM|'
             r'SYMBOLIC|SYNC|SYNCHRONIZED|TALLYING|TAPE|'
             r'TEST|THROUGH|THRU|TIME|TIMES|TO|TOP|TRAILING|'
             r'TRANSFORM|TYPE|UNDERLINE|UNIT|UNSIGNED|'
             r'UNSIGNED-INT|UNSIGNED-LONG|UNSIGNED-SHORT|UNTIL|UP|'
             r'UPDATE|UPON|USAGE|USING|VALUE|VALUES|VARYING|WAIT|WHEN|'
             r'WITH|WORDS|YYYYDDD|YYYYMMDD)'
             r'\b(?!-)', Keyword.Pseudo),
             #r'\s*($|(?=[^0-9a-z_\-]))', Keyword.Pseudo),

            # inactive reserved words
            #(r'(^|(?<=[^0-9a-z_\-]))'
            (r'\b(?!-)'
             r'(ACTIVE-CLASS|ALIGNED|ANYCASE|ARITHMETIC|ATTRIBUTE|B-AND|'
             r'B-NOT|B-OR|B-XOR|BIT|BOOLEAN|CD|CENTER|CF|CH|CHAIN|CLASS-ID|'
             r'CLASSIFICATION|COMMUNICATION|CONDITION|DATA-POINTER|'
             r'DESTINATION|DISABLE|EC|EGI|EMI|ENABLE|END-RECEIVE|'
             r'ENTRY-CONVENTION|EO|ESI|EXCEPTION-OBJECT|EXPANDS|FACTORY|'
             r'FLOAT-BINARY-16|FLOAT-BINARY-34|FLOAT-BINARY-7|'
             r'FORMAT|'
             r'GET|GROUP-USAGE|IMPLEMENTS|INFINITY|'
             r'INHERITS|INTERFACE|INTERFACE-ID|INVOKE|LC_ALL|LC_COLLATE|'
             r'LC_CTYPE|LC_MESSAGES|LC_MONETARY|LC_NUMERIC|LC_TIME|'
             r'LINE-COUNTER|MESSAGE|METHOD|METHOD-ID|NESTED|NONE|NORMAL|'
             r'OBJECT|OBJECT-REFERENCE|OPTIONS|OVERRIDE|PAGE-COUNTER|PF|PH|'
             r'PROPERTY|PROTOTYPE|PURGE|QUEUE|RAISE|RAISING|RECEIVE|'
             r'RELATION|REPLACE|REPRESENTS-NOT-A-NUMBER|RESET|RESUME|RETRY|'
             r'RF|RH|SECONDS|SEGMENT|SELF|SEND|SOURCES|STATEMENT|STEP|'
             r'STRONG|SUB-QUEUE-1|SUB-QUEUE-2|SUB-QUEUE-3|SUPER|SYMBOL|'
             r'SYSTEM-DEFAULT|TABLE|TERMINAL|TEXT|TYPEDEF|UCS-4|UNIVERSAL|'
             r'USER-DEFAULT|UTF-16|UTF-8|VAL-STATUS|VALID|VALIDATE|'
             r'VALIDATE-STATUS)\b(?!-)', Comment),
             #r'VALIDATE-STATUS)\s*($|(?=[^0-9a-z_\-]))', Comment),

            # Data Types
            (r'(^|(?<=[^0-9a-z_\-]))'
            #(r'\b(?!-)'
             r'(PIC\s+.+?(?=(\s|\.\s))|PICTURE\s+.+?(?=(\s|\.\s))|'
             r'(COMPUTATIONAL)(-[1-5X])?|(COMP)(-[1-5X])?|'
             r'BINARY-C-LONG|POINTER|PROGRAM-POINTER|'
             r'FUNCTION-POINTER|PROCEDURE-POINTER|'
             r'BINARY-CHAR|BINARY-DOUBLE|BINARY-LONG|BINARY-SHORT|'
             r'FLOAT-SHORT|FLOAT-LONG|FLOAT-DECIMAL-16|FLOAT-DECIMAL-34|'
             r'FLOAT-BINARY-32|FLOAT-BINARY-64|FLOAT-BINARY-128|'
             r'FLOAT-EXTENDED|FLOAT-DECIMAL-7|'
            # r'BINARY)\b(?!-)', Keyword.Type),
             r'BINARY)\s*($|(?=[^0-9a-z_\-]))', Keyword.Type),

            # Operators
            (r'(\*\*|\*|\+|-|/|<=|>=|<|>|==|/=|=)', Operator),

            # (r'(::)', Keyword.Declaration),

            (r'([(),;:&%.])', Punctuation),

            # Intrinsics
            #(r'(^|(?<=[^0-9a-z_\-]))(ABS|ACOS|ANNUITY|ASIN|ATAN|BYTE-LENGTH|'
            (r'\b(?!-)(ABS|ACOS|ANNUITY|ASIN|ATAN|BYTE-LENGTH|'
             r'CHAR|COMBINED-DATETIME|CONCATENATE|COS|CURRENT-DATE|'
             r'DATE-OF-INTEGER|DATE-TO-YYYYMMDD|DAY-OF-INTEGER|DAY-TO-YYYYDDD|'
             r'EXCEPTION-(?:FILE|LOCATION|STATEMENT|STATUS)|EXP10|EXP|E|'
             r'FACTORIAL|FRACTION-PART|INTEGER-OF-(?:DATE|DAY|PART)|INTEGER|'
             r'LENGTH|LOCALE-(?:DATE|TIME(?:-FROM-SECONDS)?)|LOG10|LOG|'
             r'LOWER-CASE|MAX|MEAN|MEDIAN|MIDRANGE|MIN|MOD|NUMVAL(?:-C)?|'
             r'ORD(?:-MAX|-MIN)?|PI|PRESENT-VALUE|RANDOM|RANGE|REM|REVERSE|'
             r'SECONDS-FROM-FORMATTED-TIME|SECONDS-PAST-MIDNIGHT|SIGN|SIN|SQRT|'
             r'STANDARD-DEVIATION|STORED-CHAR-LENGTH|SUBSTITUTE(?:-CASE)?|'
             r'SUM|TAN|TEST-DATE-YYYYMMDD|TEST-DAY-YYYYDDD|TRIM|'
             r'UPPER-CASE|VARIANCE|WHEN-COMPILED|YEAR-TO-YYYY)'
             r'\b(?!-)', Name.Function),
             #r'UPPER-CASE|VARIANCE|WHEN-COMPILED|YEAR-TO-YYYY)\s*'
             #r'($|(?=[^0-9a-z_\-]))', Name.Function),

            # Booleans
            #(r'(^|(?<=[^0-9a-z_\-]))(true|false)\s*($|(?=[^0-9a-z_\-]))', Name.Builtin),
            (r'\b(?!-)(true|false)\b(?!-)', Name.Builtin),
            # Comparing Operators
            #(r'(^|(?<=[^0-9a-z_\-]))(equal|equals|ne|lt|le|gt|ge|'
            # r'greater|less|than|not|and|or)\s*($|(?=[^0-9a-z_\-]))', Operator.Word),
            (r'\b(?!-)(equal|equals|ne|lt|le|gt|ge|'
             r'greater|less|than|not|and|or)\b(?!-)', Operator.Word),
        ],

        # \"[^\"\n]*\"|\'[^\'\n]*\'
        'strings': [
            # apparently strings can be delimited by EOL if they are continued
            # in the next line
            (r'"[^"\n]*("|\n)', String.Double),
            (r"'[^'\n]*('|\n)", String.Single),
        ],

        'nums': [
            #(r'\d+(\s+|\.$|$)', Number.Integer),
            (r'\b(?!-)\d+\b(?!-)', Number.Integer),
            (r'[+-]?\d*\.\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?', Number.Float),
            (r'[+-]?\d+\.\d*([eE][-+]?\d+)?', Number.Float),
        ],
    }


class CobolFreeformatLexer(CobolLexer):
    """
    Lexer for Free format OpenCOBOL code.

    *New in Pygments 1.6.*
    """
    name = 'COBOLFree'
    aliases = ['cobolfree']
    filenames = ['*.cbl', '*.CBL']
    mimetypes = []
    flags = re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE

    tokens = {
        'comment': [
            (r'(\*>.*\n|^\w*\*.*$)', Comment),
        ],
    }
```

Excuse the dead code comments, getting rid of quite a few backtracking pattern matches, still in testing and not committed to bitbucket just yet.  And this is just for pretty colours in source listings, *sans intelligence or correctness*.